# UNIT TEST- Django DRF - How to calling methods in ModelViewSets (Avoid 404 Error)

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am writing unit test code for viewsets. I often struggling for calling url to access my methods.
here, views.py

```
class AppraisalEmployeeAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ['retrieve']:
            self.permission_classes = [IsOwnerPermission | IsHODPermission | IsHRUser | 
                                         IsManagementUser]
        elif self.action in ['list']:
            self.permission_classes = [IsHRUser | IsManagementUser]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
    def list(self, request):
         # code
         return obj
    def retrieve(self, request):
         #code
        return obj
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('appraisal', AppraisalAPI)
router.register(r'employee', AppraisalEmployeeAPI, basename='employee')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

test.py

```
 url = reverse('employee-list')
    self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
    resp1 = self.client.get(url, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(resp1.status_code, 200)
```

Here, I have got 404 page not found response. I don't know how to approach viewssets by using url routers. Expecting help for above issue and how to approach viewsets and router urls.

Comment: Is `app_name` set in `urls.py`?

Comment: I registered then i got 'employee-list' is not valid pattern name(Noreversematch). I am using 2 apps login and appraisal. Iam doing test from login app test.py to appraisal views.
when i call appraisal-list its working fine(1st url). When i call employee-list its not working. I just got confused,...

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. **url = reverse('empoloyee-list')**
employee -> should be basename.
If our list function has query params we should pass params like below code,

```
url = reverse('employees-list')
        self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        resp1 = self.client.get(url, {'appraisal_id': pks1.id,
                                      'employee_type': pks2.employee_type,
                                      'organization_id': 1,
                                      'state': 'employee',
                                      'status': 'Pending'
                                      }, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(resp1.status_code, 200)
```

Now its working fine..